# can I make awk cut its input according to '\n'?

Tags: awk

we all know that we can get the columns of a line using awk, but the columns is split by white spaces:

```
cat FileName | awk ' { print $1,$2,$3 .... }'
```

but what if we want to split the files according to '\n':
for example if we have this file:

```
Hi 
Hello
Aloha
```

and we want to get the second word 'Hello' using 'awk' what should we do?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `,` is replaced by (well more like the arguments to `print` are joined with) `OFS`, not `FS`. So it's `{print $1 OFS $2 OFS $3}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk, there are two main separators: the field separator, and the record separator. The record separator separates different groups of fields. As you can probably guess from this description, the default record is a newline. You can access the current record index in the variable `NR`.

```
awk 'NR==2 { print; exit }'
```

You can also just write `awk NR==2`, but awk will (since you didn't tell it to exit after finding it) loyally continue processing the rest of the file after it reaches line 2, which might take a long time in a large file. The `exit` tells awk to exit immediately after printing record 2.

Comment: From which file-size is the `exit` approach quicker, if you include the additional typing time?

Comment: @Bernhard That's too broad to be answered without knowledge of the processing speed, the speed at which `awk` reads, and, of course, the speed at which the user types. In general, my approach when answering questions is to make the solution generalisable for the most broad number of use cases, so long as it does not compromise readability or encumber function. After all, this site is supposed to provide an environment to help more than just the original question giver. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are trying to do here, you might be able to use awk's "multi-line-record" mode. From `Gawk's` manual:

> If RS is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines. When RS is set to the null string, the newline character always acts as a field separator, in addition to whatever value FS may have.

So in your case you could get the second line like this:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' RS= FileName
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sed` to print only the second line,

```
sed -n '2p' file
```

Or:

```
sed '2!d;q' file
```

for `sed` to quit after it has read and printed the second line so it doesn't read the rest of the file.

Or:

```
head -n 2 file | tail -n 1
```

Comment: We could make sed to quit after first match by specifying q flag.